# The reputation graph date format is confusing

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph, date-format

[image]

When the reputation graph scales such that only the first of the month is labelled, I find the labelling confusing. At first I thought this was a bug because I was expecting `Nov 11, Dec 11, Jan 12` and it had been truncated.

I now realise it is referring to the day of the month. It would be clearer to switch to using `Month, Year`, or to drop the day and just have `Month`.

Comment: Hmmm, well this answers *my* question of "Does anybody actually look at the reputation graph?"...

Comment: Every time I click on the graph tab, I am disappointed to see this one instead of the old line graph...

Comment: @AShelly I hear you on that one